# V-for Vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting an error with my v-for

```
[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
An error occurred while rendering the page. Check developer tools console for details.
```

Here is the class that is throwing the error.

```
<b-row>
    <b-col v-for="favorite in favorites" :key="favorite.id">
      <FavoriteCard :favoriteId="favorite" />
    </b-col>
</b-row>
...
export default Vue.extend({
async mounted() {
  if (this.isAuthenticated) {
    await this.$store.dispatch("myStore/getAllFavorites");
  }
},
computed: {
  favorites: function() {
    let favorites = this.$store.getters['myStore/getFavorites'];
    return favorites;
  }
}
})
```

And FavoriteCard.vue

```
<template>
<b-card @>
    <nuxt-link :to="this.favoriteId.link" :id="'favorite' + this.favoriteId.id">{{this.favoriteId.title}}</nuxt-link>
</b-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropOptions } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: "FavoriteCard",
    props: {
        favoriteId: {
            type:Object,
            required:true
        }
    }
};
```

And my store

```
const state = () => ({
favorites: []
})
const mutations = {
  setFavorites (state, favorites) {
state.favorites = favorites
},
createNewFavorite (state, favorite, isMonograph) {
state.favorites.push(favorite, isMonograph);
},
deleteFavorite (state, favorite) {
let index = state.favorites.map(function(f) {return f.id}).indexOf(favorite.id);
state.favorites.splice(index, 1);
},
}
const getters = {
  getFavorites: (state) => {
return state.favorites;
},
}
const actions = {
    async getAllFavorites ({ commit  }) {
let { data } = await this.$axios.get(`/favorites`);
commit('setFavorites', data);
},
}
```

When I try to update the store, I get an error that I shouldn't mutate the vuex store state outside of mutation handlers. What should I do to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't seem to contain the code that is responsible for this

Comment: What useful code should I include?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Nothing in the code you showed so far indicates the warning was initiated from the component you think initiated it. Look for more details in the developer console, it probably gives you more details about its root source. You need to include those details. Ideally you should provide a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar. Make sure it reproduces the bug.